# Autodesk Forge third party updater dialog issue

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

We can open Revit files on Autodesk forge but recently we have run into a Revit file that have content from a third party plugin. When you open the file manually you get this dialog:

[image]

We think this dialog is causing this file to stop from loading the file further. Our question is how can we suppress this dialog.

Comment: Hi,@Daniel, did you try [Custom Failure Handling](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/revit_specific/handling-failures/) to suppress this warning? Or in above dialog, select 2nd option "Do not warn about... an continue working with the file" and save the file, then provide the new one for Design Automation?

Comment: Not yet, thank you! we will look into it

Comment: Please review the follow up of my colleague

Answer (score 0):

We've added the Custom Failure Handling (as suggested), but it seems that this code is not even executed: we don't see any logs. The failure seems to occur directly after our log when our plugin starts (see `** Plugin code starts here.`)

```
...
Running RevitAssemblyResolver....
Initializing RevitCoreEngine...
Selected Revit\RCE install Path: (from app.config) C:\RevitDir
Resolving location of Revit/RevitCoreEngine installation...
Running user application....
Found an addIn for registration: PlugIn01.addin
Initializing RCE....
Initializing RevitCoreEngine (and possibly running stub installer)...
Language not specified, using English as default
application.ActiveAddInId.GetGUID() = 000bd853-36e4-461f-9171-c5aceda4e724
** Plugin code starts here.
Initialize and  get RCE: (VersionBuild) 18.0.0.0 (VersionNumber) 2018 (SubVersionNumber) 2018.3
Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.InternalException: An internal error has occurred.
   at Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.Application.OpenDocumentFile(ModelPath modelPath, OpenOptions openOptions)
   at DesignAutomationFramework.DesignAutomationData..ctor(Application revitApp, String mainModelPath)
   at DesignAutomationFramework.DesignAutomationReadyEventArgs..ctor(Application revitApp, String mainModelPath)
   at DesignAutomationFramework.DesignAutomationBridge.SetDesignAutomationReady(Application revitApp, String mainModelPath)
   at RevitCoreEngineTest.RceConsoleApplication.Program.UserMain(CommandLineArgs cl)
RESULT: Failure - Result of running user app is failure
Finished running.  Process will return: TestError
====== Revit finished running: revitcoreconsole ======
...
```

What we eventually did to have a successful run, was to recreate a new central file. Maybe the file was corrupt to start with.

Comment: Congratulations on resolving this and thank you for letting us know.